# How do I generate a client from OpenApi documentation made by OpenApi Generator?

Tags: openapi, arcgis, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am looking at these API docs https://developers.arcgis.com/workflow-manager/api-reference/rest/ which appear to be made by OpenApi Generator (some links at the bottom).

I want to generate a C# client using the openapi-generator-cli which requires a YAML file as input. How do I get that YAML file out of those docs?

Comment: I think one way is to contact the team supporting the Workflow Manager API to get a copy of the OpenAPI spec directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up asking Esri: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-workflow-manager-questions/is-there-a-spec-for-wm-server-api/m-p/1240965#M1763

`https://<server>/<webadaptor>/workflow/doc/swagger.json`